# Progressive matrix puzzle with straight and curved hatches

Tags: visual, pattern, progressive-matrix

What's the solution to this raven's advanced progressive matrix, and why?
[image]

The matrix was found on this paper: https://www.hrpub.org/download/20190830/UJER21-19513535.pdf

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is

> #5.

because

> If you look at the three symbols in any row or column, and only look at either the horizontal or the vertical lines of the symbols, you will find that one of them has one line, one has two lines, and one has three lines. Also, one uses thin lines, one uses thick curved lines, and one uses outlines/rectangles.
>  The only symbol that completes that pattern for both the horizontal and the vertical lines is #5.